# How to determine if text loupe is active on UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios

On this app I'm working with, I have a need to be aware when the text loupe is active (so I can ignore the dragging motion event in my app).

I've tried hooking into the `UITextViewDelegate` methods, especially the `textViewDidChangeSelection:`, but that only gets called AFTER the touch event ends and the loupe is dismissed by the system.

I also tried monitoring the `didEditingBegin/End` notifications - but that is no go either.

I need to know when the loupe becomes active, in addition to, not just when its dismissed.  Anyone have any insight?